# Magento Add tax on Discount Price in cart

Tags: tax, sales

I want to apply tax on the total that comes after applying discount such as coupon.
Let me explain you further:
Suppose I have a product in cart that costs 1700 and applied a coupon of FLAT40 which is 40% discount. Now the cart totals are as follows:
Sub total = 1700
Discount (FLAT40) = -680
Grand Total = 1020

Now I want to apply a tax of 12.5% of Grand Total which is 1020. I am not able to achieve using magento's tax rules and tax settings.
Can someone help me how can I achieve my goal.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple:

Goto System->Configuration->Sales->Tax and do settings as shown in screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Dexter, my catalog prices (e.g. 1700) are including tax and I  want to apply discount on that. You solution is not working for me.

Comment: if your catalog price ie: 1700 is including tax why you want to apply it again ? i am not clear on it.

Answer (score 1):

here is my understanding: you want change the price two times, one for coupon and one for tax.

Two things should be done:

1. create coupon that gives 40% discount, here is the [tutorial](http://support.argoworks.com/entries/195532-How-do-I-add-a-promo-code-or-coupon-code-to-Magento-)
2. set up the tax

And you might give us more information about why you did not achieve your goal, more explanations or images will help a lot

Thank you